# PHP: How are comments skipped?

Tags: php, language-design, comments

Well if I comment something it's skipped in all languages, but how are they skipped and what is readed?

Example:

```
// This is commented out
```

Now does PHP reads the whole comment to go to next lines or just reads the `//`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. Having read the '//', it then *has to* keep reading to the newline to find it. There's no choice about this. There is no other way to *find* the newline.

Conceptually, compiling has several phases that are logically prior to parsing:

1. Scanning.
2. Screening.
3. Tokenization.

(1) basically means reading the file character by character from left to right.
(2) means throwing things away of no interest, e.g. collapsing multiple newline/whitespace sequences to a single space.
(3) means combining what's left into tokens, e.g. identifiers, keywords, literals, punctuation.

Comments are screened out during (2). In modern compilers this is all done at once by a deterministic automaton.

Answer (score 7):

The script is parsed and split into *tokens*.

You can actually try this out yourself on any valid PHP source code using [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), it uses PHP's native tokenizer.

The example from the manual shows how a comment is dealt with:

```
<?php
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php echo; ?>'); /* => array(
                                                  array(T_OPEN_TAG, '<?php'), 
                                                  array(T_ECHO, 'echo'),
                                                  ';',
                                                  array(T_CLOSE_TAG, '?>') ); */

/* Note in the following example that the string is parsed as T_INLINE_HTML
   rather than the otherwise expected T_COMMENT (T_ML_COMMENT in PHP <5).
   This is because no open/close tags were used in the "code" provided.
   This would be equivalent to putting a comment outside of <?php ?> 
   tags in a normal file. */

$tokens = token_get_all('/* comment */'); 
// => array(array(T_INLINE_HTML, '/* comment */'));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a tokenization phase while compiling.  During this phase, it see the // and then just ignores everything to the end of the line.  Compilers CAN get complicated, but for the most part are pretty straight forward.

http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/