# Does PHP parser takes microtime while reading comments

Tags: php, parsing, time, process, comments

**Read Carefully**

The question here is not that does PHP parser processes comments or not nor the question is about, that does omitting comments give more performance to your script or not!

Its about, that **" Does PHP parser spend a microtime while reading comments? "**

**Why I am asking?**

Due to the misconception over Internet World regarding this question. Some programmers says 'YES' and some answers 'NO'. Who should I obay ?

Edit: (After getting mostly comments and answer claiming to spend microtime on comments)

**Look What I've got here**

```
<?php

// Control
echo microtime(), "<br />"; // 0.25163600 1292450508
echo microtime(), "<br />"; // 0.25186000 1292450508

// Test
echo microtime(), "<br />"; // 0.25189700 1292450508
# TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
# .. Above comment repeated 18809 times ..
echo microtime(), "<br />"; // 0.25192100 1292450508

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do php comments take server time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445364/do-php-comments-take-server-time)

Comment: Even if this is the case - those microseconds will be time well spent.  Keep the comments!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well one can say. But I cannot still find my answer under your given link. Take a look if you can find

Comment: There's an instruction telling the parser to skip the commented part of the text in the code. If that instruction has to be executed, then yes, CPU cycles are spent on executing that skip command. However, we're not talking about entire seconds of CPU cycles, we're talking miniature numbers here. Therefore, it's probably not even worth mentioning since it's on a nanosecond level.

Comment: You're asking *"Does PHP parser spend a microtime while reading comments?"* but you state you're not asking *"does PHP parser processes comments"*. They seem mutually exclusive. What are you asking? Are you asking if PHP processes comments for some kind of functionality?

Comment: @MikeB I said that because I know that some people will try to answer on that. Php parser does processes comments. Everyone knows that

Comment: @YousufIqbal: Answers at that question include things like "*parse rules for "jumping" over comments are well established and extremely low-overhead. removing comments will save a miniscule sliver of processing time, but you will never notice it.*" - how does that not address your question?

Comment: So what are you asking? If the PHP parser takes up cpu cycles while parsing the comments? If you know the parser goes over the comments then you also know it uses cpu cycles... There's no way the parser some how goes over the comments magically without using any processing power.

Comment: @MikeB I am doing a Special edit for you. Take a look at my question in a while. Thanks

Comment: @YousufIqbal: Your code snippet doesn't tell you anything useful.  The code isn't executed until its parsed, and even if it was, attempting to measure such tiny amounts of time is inherently inaccurate on a CPU.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So whats the story ended with ?

Comment: Are you asking about the 2.4 hundred-thousands of a second difference for going over 18k lines of comments? IMHO that's too small a value to be meaningful. Skip to the conclusions programmers should draw from this knowledge. The trade-off is to write comments that vastly help maintainability of code.. or shaving .000024 seconds off request time?

Comment: @YousufIqbal: As everyone has already said, parsing comments takes non-zero time.

Comment: All the comment parsing happens before any code is executed, while the opcode is being generated (doesn't it?) so it won't affect the time taken *during* execution of your code. Any discrepancies you see between the duration between `microtime()` calls are nothing to do with the amount comments or their position in your script.

Comment: @YousufIqbal: It should also be pointed out that 18000 lines, each 80 characters long, is 1.4 MB; this will take something like 10 **milli** seconds to read from disk (although the OS cache and the PHP pre-compiler will amortize that cost on subsequent requests).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth End of story: **" It takes non-zero time "**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it takes some microseconds (yes it will, your file has to be parsed, right?!), you shouldn't remove them. First thing to do is to cache the byte code, so the PHP interpreter doesn't have to reparse the "plain text" code to byte code. I think you can get a lot more performance gain out of that, rather than worrying about comments taking up parse time.

It seems to be indeed a duplicate to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445364/do-php-comments-take-server-time). (Note to self, first refresh the page before submitting.)

Comment: Basically your test shows you the answer: yes it takes some microseconds to process the comments.